# Mensagem de sucesso apos troca de senha

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Quero mostrar uma mensagem de sucesso após o usuario trocar de senha, com bootstrap e PHP.

Segue o que eu to tentando fazer:

```
if($login == null){
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    $_SESSION['mensagem'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Senha alterada com sucesso!</div>';
}
die();
```

E chamando a variavel na pagina onde deve aparecer a mensagem:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['mensagem'] ;?>
```

Comment: Você está iniciando a session no lado Dashboard.php e no lado desse arquivo com o header location ? Se sim, isso está ok, se não, inicie a session em ambas as partes, após isso, altere o header: 'Location: htttp://seudominio/dashboard.php', comente se resolver ou não

Comment: Era o link completo! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Informar um `location` no `header` necessita que você informe o endereço inteiro de direcionamento, exemplo:

```
if($login == null){
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    header("Location: http://seudominio/dashboard.php");
    $_SESSION['mensagem'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Senha alterada com sucesso!</div>';
}
die();
```